# Views count not updating in Next.js with Prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, prisma, next.js13

I’m building a blog application using Next.js and Prisma. I have a page where I display a post based on its ID and I want to increment the views count each time this page is fetched. However, the views count doesn’t change at all.

Here’s the relevant code:

page.tsx:

```
timport BackButton from "@/components/BackButton";
import Badge from "@/components/Badge";
import DeleteButton from "@/components/DeleteButton";
import Like from "@/components/Like";
import Views from "@/components/Views";
import { Tag } from "@prisma/client";
import { Pencil } from "lucide-react";
import Link from "next/link";

interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

interface Post {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  tag: Tag;
  views: number;
  likes: number;
}

const getPost = async ({ params }: Props): Promise<Post> => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${params.id}`, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });
  return res.json();
};

const DetailPage = async ({ params }: Props) => {
  const post = await getPost({ params });
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 max-w-lg">
      <BackButton href="/posts" />
      <div className="flex justify-between gap-1 items-baseline max-w-sm">
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">{post.title}</h1>
        {post.tag && <Badge tag={post.tag.name} />}
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-start gap-4 items-baseline max-w-sm">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
          <Link href={`/posts/edit/${post.id}`} className="btn btn-warning">
            <Pencil /> Edit
          </Link>
          <DeleteButton params={params} />
        </div>
        <Views views={post.views} />
        <Like likes={post.likes} />
      </div>
      <p className="max-w-md">{post.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DetailPage;
```

route.tsx:

```
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }: Props) {
  try {
    const post = await prisma.post.update({
      where: {
        id: params.id,
      },
      data: {
        views: {
          increment: 1,
        },
      },
      select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
        content: true,
        tag: true,
        views: true,
        likes: true,
      },
    });
    return NextResponse.json(post, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Could not fecth the post" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

views.tsx:

```
import { Eye } from "lucide-react";

interface Props {
  views: number;
}

const Views = ({ views }: Props) => {
  console.log("****Views****: ", views);
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-1 items-center">
      <Eye size={23} />
      <span className="font-bold text-sm">{views}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Views;
```

prisma.schema.ts:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Tag {
  id   String @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  name String
  post Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String
  content   String
  views     Int      @default(0)
  likes     Int      @default(0)
  tag       Tag?     @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
  tagId     String
}
```

- I’ve tried fetching the post before incrementing the views count, fetching the post after incrementing the views count, and even fetching and incrementing in one query using update method with select. However, none of these solutions worked.
- I’m not creating a new instance of Prisma Client on every request and my database connection is stable. There are no errors being thrown when I’m trying to update the views count.

Does anyone know why the views count might not be updating and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the views functionality. The problem occurred because I had created some posts before I defined the views field in the prisma.schema.ts file. As a result, these posts did not have the views field in the database. To fix this, I used Prisma Studio to assign random views counts to each post manually. After that, all posts had the views count working properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).